# why Linq to sql can't track update information if we directly assign new object value to old .?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
Customer customer = (from x in db.Customers where x.CustomerID.Equals(cust.CustomerID.Value) select x).SingleOrDefault();

customer = newcustomer;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

by executing the above code I am able to get new data into the customer object,
But by executing `SubmitChanges()` its can't update into the database.

I need to write following kind of mechanism to update value into database.

```
customer.CustomerName = "James";
customer.DisplayName = "Jimmy";

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Is there any suggestion for that ?

Comment: Go to the setter of any property of customer and look what is going on with change tracker. Then figure out why just changing reference don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so, because you change the reference that `customer` points to. So the ORM lose the changes you make to the object you retrieve from the database. Actually, when you fetch a record from the dabase for a specific customer like below:

```
Customer customer = (from x in db.Customers 
                     where x.CustomerID.Equals(cust.CustomerID.Value) 
                     select x).SingleOrDefault();
```

You create an object, whose properties have the values that are in the record you fetched. When later you change for instance the value of the `CustomerName`

```
customer.CustomerName = "James";
```

and then you call the `SubmitChanges` method:

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

a process runs, which detects any changes made to the object. This process finds that you have changed the value of `CustomerName` and the appopriate UPDATE statement would be created by the ORM. Last this statement is sent to the database, in order to be executed.

On the other hand if you change the value of `customer`, the *changes detection* process would decide that nothing changed regarding the retrieved record. Why this happens is due to the fact that *the only way the ORM is aware of the record is through the reference it has to the created object after the retrieval*. Changing this you lose it from your context.

Answer (score 0):

If you see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378(v=vs.110).aspx), you get the answer.

> Regardless of how many changes you make to your objects, changes are
> made only to in-memory replicas. You have made no changes to the
> actual data in the database
>
> When you call SubmitChanges, LINQ to SQL examines the set of known objects >to determine whether new instances have been attached to them. If they have, >these new instances are added to the set of tracked objects.

There are 2 statements

```
customer = newcustomer;
```

this statement just update the value or reference in memory.

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

This statement commit the all changes i.e insert, update, delete statement in memory to db end with proper validate the record.

So we need use second statement whenever we need to force and update the data.